# Circle Trigonometry is it possible?

Tags: calculus

How is it possible that

r = 3 sin θ  Its equal to a circle with 3/2 of radious ??

and what other trigonometrys forms can be possible on circle?? Sorry for my bad math.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r%3D3sin%28theta%29&t=ff3tb01)?

Comment: Do you know that your function is in polar coordinates and not the common "(x,y)" coordinate system?

Comment: Yes i do really know that, but why 3/2 of radious?

Answer (score 2):

The (polar) equation describes the circle with diameter from $x=0,\,y=0$ to $x=0,\,y=3$.

Algebraic reason:
$$\eqalign{r=3\sin\theta
  &\Leftrightarrow r^2=3r\sin\theta\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=3y\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2-3y=0\cr}$$
and now complete the square.

Geometric reason: draw the circle, let $O$ be the origin, let $N$ be the point $x=0,\,y=3$ and let $P$ be any point on the circle.  Then $\angle OPN$ is a right angle and $OP=r$ and $ON=3$, so
$$r=OP\cos\angle PON=3\cos\Bigl(\frac\pi2-\theta\Bigr)=3\sin\theta\ .$$

Comment: One more question, why r = 4csc θ is a line in y = 4 going horizontal? ¿Why it changed from circle to line?

Comment: Because $\csc\theta=1/\sin\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: More explained please?

Comment: Substitute $\csc\theta=1/\sin\theta$ into your equation and simplify.  It's easy algebra, I'm sure you can do it.

Comment: I figured it out thank you :D